# restoreCompletedTransactions() not working

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am trying to restore Non-Consumable IAP with SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions() and nothing work according to plan. In sandbox I get "There's no information available for In-App Purchases. Try again later. 21105" and in Prod just nothing happens. From what I can see that error in Sandbox is thrown with actual SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions() line and nothing is processed after that. I am sure everything is right, since I can make my purchase by hand and it works, I can also repurchase anything again with error, that I already have it and then item get activated, but Restore button is not working (restorePurchases()). I do have 38 IAP in this app, but I am not sure if that is related in any way, and they all are Non-Consumable. It is iMessage Extension that sells stickers. What is also strange, is that Apple did kick my app back because I used my Own Art without My own permission (that was hilarious), but everything states, that with Non-Consumable must have Restore and Apple check for that, and in this case everything passed while it is not working.

My IAP class is:

```
import Foundation
import StoreKit
import os.log


class IAPService: NSObject
{
    private override init() {} // make sure there is no extra copies

    static let shared = IAPService() // makes this singleton
    fileprivate var products = [SKProduct]()
    let paymentQueue = SKPaymentQueue.default()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    var haveData = false
    var reference = StickewrsCollectionViewController()
    fileprivate var request = SKProductsRequest()
    let log = OSLog(subsystem: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!, category: "IAPService")

    let receiptFetcher = ReceiptFetcher()


    func getProducts()
    {
        let allStickersIAP = “IAP reference”
        var iapList = Dictionary<String, String>()
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "StickersData", ofType: ".plist")
        {
            let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
            let globalData = dict["StickerData"] as! Array<AnyObject>
            iapList = (globalData[1]) as! Dictionary<String, String>
        }
        var products: Set = [allStickersIAP]
        for iap in iapList
        {
            products.insert(iap.value)
        }
        request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: products)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
        paymentQueue.add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        os_log("Getting products")


    }

    func purchase(product: String)
    {
        if (SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments())
        {
            guard let productToPurchase = products.filter({$0.productIdentifier == product}).first
            else {return}

            let payment = SKPayment(product: productToPurchase)
            paymentQueue.add(payment)
        }
    }

    func restorePurchases()
    {
        print("Restoring purchases")
        os_log("Restoring purchases")

        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

    }

    func iapCheck() -> Bool
    {
        return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() && haveData
    }

    func getProductData(iap: String) -> SKProduct
    {
        return products.filter({$0.productIdentifier == iap}).first ?? SKProduct()
    }

    func priceStringForProduct(item: SKProduct) -> String? {
        let price = item.price
        if price == NSDecimalNumber(decimal: 0.00) {
            return NSLocalizedString("free", comment: "") 
        } else {
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            let locale = item.priceLocale
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            numberFormatter.locale = locale
            return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
        }
    }

    func setReference(ref: StickewrsCollectionViewController)
    {
        reference = ref
    }

    public func passPopUp(_ text: String)
    {
        reference.ShowPopUp(text)
    }

    // Called when the application is about to terminate.
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Remove the observer.
        SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
    }

}

extension IAPService: SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver
{
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        products = response.products

        haveData = true
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
           switch  transaction.transactionState
            {
                case .purchasing: break
                case .purchased:
                    do {
                        defaults.set(true, forKey: transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                        defaults.synchronize() // save changes in PlayerPrefs
                        print(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                        queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                        }
            case .restored:
                do {
                    print("Do actual restoring")
                    os_log("Now restoring %@",  transaction.original!.payment.productIdentifier)
                    reference.ShowPopUp("Restoring purchase \(transaction.original!.payment.productIdentifier)")
                    defaults.set(true, forKey: transaction.original!.payment.productIdentifier)
                    defaults.synchronize() // save changews in PlayerPrefs
                    print(transaction.payment.productIdentifier)
                    queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                }
                default: queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
        reference.redrawnAfterPurchase()
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            let t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            defaults.set(true, forKey: prodID)
            defaults.synchronize() // save changews in PlayerPrefs
            print(prodID)
            queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
        }
        reference.redrawnAfterPurchase()
        reference.ShowPopUp(NSLocalizedString("restoreCompleted", comment: ""))
    }

}

extension SKPaymentTransactionState
{
    func status() -> String
    {
        switch self {
        case .deferred: return "deferred"
        case .failed: return "failed"
        case .purchased: return "purchased"
        case .purchasing: return "purchasing"
        case .restored: return "restored"

        }
    }
}
```

Whart I did wrong and how I can make RestorePurchases actually do something ?

Comment: Probably not your issue, but your code in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is incorrect. You can use this method to update any UI or perform any other housekeeping required when the restoration process is complete. You don't process any transactions in this method. You also don't need to call `synchronize` on `UserDefaults`

Comment: I do exactly same actions in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` and `paymentQueue` as many tutorials and examples points to both cases, but in sandbox I never get that far during Restore process

Comment: As I said, that probably isn't your problem, but your code in `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` is incorrect.  I am not surprised tutorials get it wrong. It is a common misconception. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506101-paymentqueuerestorecompletedtran)

Comment: What value do you get passed to [paymentQueue(_:restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymenttransactionobserver/1506063-paymentqueue)?

Comment: that is the thing - I never get there from `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished`, I just get error that there is nothing to restore with error code 21105. Any chance I needed to mark my Non-Consumable IAP explicitly somewhere to be restorable ?

Comment: Where do you get that error?  In which function call?

Comment: After some investigation it seems that is related only to iMessage app extension, and it seems others have the same issue [https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/111646]

Comment: @Burve Did you find any solution for restoring purchase in iMessage App ?
 Because i'm receiving the same error ("There's no information available for In-App Purchases. Try again later. 21105")